# offset in glm() vs predict.glm() in R

Tags: r

I'm confused by the (apparent) inconsistency in defining an offset in glm() which should be log-transformed (per above) and in predict.glm() using newdata which does not use log-transformed offset.

I construct a data set with 5 "treatments" each with lambda=2. The only difference is in the time over which counts are made, i.e., the offset.

```
    pmean <- 2
    Offset <- rep(c(10,31.6,100,316,1000),5)

    set.seed(7919)
    data <- data.frame(cnt = rpois(length(Offset),pmean*Offset),
                       trt = factor(rep(c("A","B","C","D","E"),5)),
                       Offset = Offset)
```

I fit two glm models, one with no offset, the other that includes the offset. Because the link is log, the offset variable must be logged when input into the model. From glm() documentation: the offset is "an *a priori* known component to be included in the *linear predictor* during fitting"

```
    noOffsetModel <- glm(cnt ~ trt, family = poisson(log), data = data)
    noOffsetModel

    # Call:  glm(formula = cnt ~ trt, family = poisson(log), data = data)
    # 
    # Coefficients:
    # (Intercept)         trtB         trtC         trtD         trtE  
    #       2.845        1.395        2.435        3.629        4.746  
    # 
    # Degrees of Freedom: 24 Total (i.e. Null);  20 Residual
    # Null Deviance:        20740 
    # Residual Deviance: 21.29  AIC: 209.3

    OffsetModel <- glm(cnt ~ trt, family = poisson(log), offset = log(Offset), data = data)
    OffsetModel

    # Call:  glm(formula = cnt ~ trt, family = poisson(log), data = data, 
    #     offset = log(Offset))
    # 
    # Coefficients:
    # (Intercept)         trtB         trtC         trtD         trtE  
    #      0.5423       0.2444       0.1327       0.1761       0.1409  
    # 
    # Degrees of Freedom: 24 Total (i.e. Null);  20 Residual
    # Null Deviance:        29.64 
    # Residual Deviance: 21.29  AIC: 209.3
```

I create two data frames for the structure of the predicted data, i.e., for predictions for a single unit of time, i.e., with an offset = 1, and another where the offset is log-transformed, i.e., log(1) = 0.

```
    preddata  <- data.frame(trt = unique(data$trt), Offset = 1)
    preddata0 <- data.frame(trt = unique(data$trt), Offset = 0)
```

When I call predict.glm for the noOffset model using newdata = preddata, I get predictions on the original count scale, which is expected because there was no Offset in the model.

```
    exp(predict.glm(noOffsetModel, newdata = preddata, type = "link"))
    # [1]   17.2   69.4  196.4  648.2 1980.2
```

When I call predict.glm for the Offset model without giving it a newdata= I get predictions on the original count scale, which again is to be expected.

```
    unique(exp(predict.glm(OffsetModel, type = "link")))
    # [1]   17.2   69.4  196.4  648.2 1980.2
```

When I call predict.glm with newdata = preddata (i.e., with Offset = 1) I get predictions that take the offset into account - values are approximately 2 for all treatments. This is not expected because the Offset in the preddata was not log-transformed even though the Offset in the original call to glm was.

```
    exp(predict.glm(OffsetModel, newdata = preddata, type = "link"))
    # [1] 1.720000 2.196203 1.964000 2.051266 1.980200
```

When I log-transform my Offset in preddata0, consistent with how I need to enter offset() in the original glm(), I get garbage

```
    exp(predict.glm(OffsetModel, newdata = preddata0, type = "link"))
    # 1 2 3 4 5 
    # 0 0 0 0 0
```

It seems very inconsistent (and prone to error) to require an offset on the original count scale in predict.glm(newdata=.) when in glm() the value in offset must be log-transformed for a log link.

Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Is this better, Parfait? It's my first posting so I'm not exactly sure of the format you're seeking. I don't see any > in my code. But I highlighted it and indented all 4 spaces. I'm familiar with rmd formatting. Is that what I should use? i.e., ```{r label}

Answer (score 1):

Might have lost track of the question somehow, but below is why you do not need to provide log.

Underneath `predict.glm`, `predict.lm` is called , and these lines are relevant to your question:

```
predict.lm
[...]
offset <- rep(0, nrow(X))
if (!is.null(off.num <- attr(tt, "offset"))) 
   for (i in off.num) offset <- offset + eval(attr(tt,"variables")[[i + 1]],newdata)
if (!is.null(object$call$offset)) 
offset <- offset + eval(object$call$offset, newdata)
```

We look at your object:

```
OffsetModel$call$offset
log(Offset)
```

So when you do predict.glm, it goes through `eval(object$call$offset, newdata)` and adds the log(Offset) to make your prediction. For example, you can try:

```
eval(OffsetModel$call$offset, preddata)
[1] 0 0 0 0 0
```

You can read the rest of the code for predict.lm, the offset is added as a predictor.

Bottom line is, if you called offet=log().., the predict.glm will also treat your  column the same way in newdata